# Angular - How to customize color for boolean in @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable

Tags: angular

In Angular-12 @tusharghoshbd ngx-datatable, I have this code:

pipe:

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toBoolean'
})
export class ToBooleanPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
    switch (value) {
      case true:
      case 'true':
      case 1:
      case '1':
        return "True";
      default:
        return "False";
    }
  }
}
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "message": "You have successfully Retrieved User Detail",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "user": {
      "id": 2,
      "department_id": 2,
      "first_name": "Frank",
      "active": "1",
      "last_name": "Akram",
      "roles": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Manager"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Supervisor"
        }
      ],
      "department": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Account"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

compnent:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  SUserInfoService
} from '../suser-info.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-info',
  templateUrl: './site-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./site-info.component.css']
})
export class SiteInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('actionTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  actionTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('addressTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  addressTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('activeTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  activeTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('departmentTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  departmentTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('rolesTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  rolesTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;
  @ViewChild('idTpl', {
    static: true
  })
  idTpl: TemplateRef < any > ;

  isLoading: boolean = false;
  options: any = {};
  userInfoList: any[] = [];
  columns: any = {};

  constructor(private userInfoService: SUserInfoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = {
      loader: true
    };
    this.columns = [{
        key: 'id',
        title: '<div class="blue"> ID</div>',
        width: 60,
        sorting: true,
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        vAlign: {
          head: 'bottom',
          body: 'middle'
        },
        cellTemplate: this.idTpl
      },
      {
        key: 'first_name',
        title: '<div class="blue">First Name</div>',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'last_name',
        title: '<div class="blue">Last Name</div>',
        width: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'department',
        title: '<div class="blue">Department</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.departmentTpl
      },
      {
        key: 'roles',
        title: '<div class="blue">Roles</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.rolesTpl
      },
      {
        key: 'active',
        title: '<div class="blue">Active</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'left'
        },
        width: 100,
        sorting: true,
        cellTemplate: this.activeTpl
      },
      {
        key: '',
        title: '<div class="blue">Action</div>',
        align: {
          head: 'center',
          body: 'center'
        },
        sorting: false,
        width: 80,
        cellTemplate: this.actionTpl
      }
    ];

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.userInfoService.getAllUserDetail().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.userInfoList = [data.results.user];

        this.options = {
          ...this.options,
          loader: false
        };
      },
      error => {
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ngx-datatable tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" [data]="userInfoList" [columns]="columns" [options]="options">
  <ngx-caption>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-6 ">
        <b>
                  <i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Site Info. List
              </b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-caption>

  <ng-template #idTpl let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-row="row">
    {{rowIndex+1}}
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #addressTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #actionTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">

  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #activeTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    <span class="badge bg-success">{{columnValue | toBoolean}}</span>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #departmentTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    {{columnValue.name}}
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #rolesTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
    <ng-template ngFor let-obj [ngForOf]="columnValue">
      {{ obj.name }}
      <br />
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>

</ngx-datatable>
```

active (toBoolean) can either be 0 or 1.

When active is 0, I want to display:

```
<span class="badge bg-danger">{{columnValue | toBoolean}}</span>
```

and when it is 1, display:

```
<span class="badge bg-auccess">{{columnValue | toBoolean}}</span>
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`[ngClass]`** for assigning CSS class conditionally.

### Solution 1

```
<span class="badge" [ngClass]="(columnValue == '1') ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-danger'">{{columnValue | toBoolean}}</span>
```

---

### Solution 2

```
<span class="badge" [ngClass]="{'bg-success': columnValue == '1', 'bg-danger': (columnValue == '0')}">{{columnValue | toBoolean}}</span>
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jwtngw)

Comment: Thanks so much. But if I want to extend it from being a boolean to 1,2,3 and 4. Then Number represent a color. How will it go hear?

Comment: You may use Solution 2, with each class need to fulfill the condition.